# How To display Subset Of Object In React Js

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, api

How To Display Subitem of Object? I am able To Display  Item But I can't display Subitem. Here is attached the image.

[image]

I can't display comments section in Object.
I am using Django API and trying to display in react js. And if you want some more details regarding this I can share with you.
Please help me

Thanks

```
      import React, { Component } from 'react'
      import axios from 'axios';
      import Iframe from 'react-iframe'
      import { Row ,Container,Col,Media } from 'react-bootstrap';


      class Details extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
            question: [],
          };
        }


        async componentDidMount() {
          const { match: { params } } = this.props;
          const question = (await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/movie/${params.pk}`)).data;
          console.log(question)
          this.setState({
            question,
          });
        }

        render() {

          const {question} = this.state;
          if (question === null) return <p>Loading ...</p>;

          return (
            <Container className="de">
            <Row>
            <Col sm={5} >
                <img className="card-img-top image" src={question.murl} alt="{{ post.name }}" style={{height: "480px"}} />
            </Col>

            <Col sm={7} >
              <h1 className="name text-white">{ question.name }</h1>
              <p className="star" ><i className="fa fa-calendar df" ></i>  { question.mdate } 
              <span style={{marginLeft: "20px"}}><i className="fa fa-star-o df" ></i>  { question.rating }/10 </span>
              <span style={{marginLeft: "20px"}}><i className="fa fa-clock-o df"></i>  { question.movietime } </span></p>
              <p className="star" >{ question.mtype  }</p>
              <h2 style={{color:"palegreen", fontFamily: "Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif"}}>{ question.body  }</h2>
              <h5 className="star" style={{textAlign:"justify"}}>{ question.description  }</h5>
              <h6 style={{color:"palegreen",marginTop:"15px"}}>Director : <span className="star">{ question.director  }</span></h6>
              <h6 style={{color:"palegreen",marginTop:"15px"}}>Main Cast : <span className="star">{ question.maincast  }</span></h6>
            </Col>

            </Row>

            <Model className="headerr" style={{marginTop: "30px"}}>
            <h2 className="text-white" >{ question.name } Trailer </h2>
            <hr className="hr" />
            {/* <iframe width="100%"  height="400" src={question.ytube} ></iframe> */}
            <Iframe url={question.ytube}
              width="100%"  height="400"
              id="myId"
              className="myClassname"
              display="initial"
              position="relative"
              allowFullScreen/>

            </Model>

      <h2 className="text-white" >Cast And Crews </h2><hr className="hr" />
      <Row>

      <Col sm={2} style={{marginTop: "15px"}} >

      <Media className="card" >
          <img className="card-img-top image" src="" alt="Just" style={{height: "210px", width: "155px", border: "1px solid rgba(137, 255, 162, 0.78) }}"}}  />
            <div className="middle">
              <p className="p">lol</p>
              <p className="p">Rol</p>
              <p className="p">mn</p>
            </div>
          </Media>
      </Col>

        </Row>

            </Container>
          )
        }
      }

      export default Details;
```

Answer (score 0):

comments is an array in your api response so you can use .map on it to render comments something like below inside  render’s return

```
   {Array.isArray(question) && question.map(q => {
        return (
             <div key={q.pk}>
                {q.cname}
                {q.cmname}
                {q.role}
             </div>
         )
   })}
```